# ZF2 How to orWhere()

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am trying to figure out how to make a Mysql Select with an OR in where Clause. By default all clauses in where statement are ANDed and after some hours of try and fail and looking the net can't make it work. In ZF1 it would be an orWhere() but there is not in ZF2.

This is the code i have inside a `AbstracttableGateway`:

```
$resultSet = $this->select(function (Select $select) use ($searchstring) {
             $select->join('users','blog_posts.id_user = users.id',array('name'))
                    ->join('blog_categories','blog_posts.id_category = blog_categories.id', array(
                                           'cat_name'   => 'name',
                                           'cat_alias' => 'alias',
                                           'cat_image'  => 'icon'))
                    ->order('date DESC');
                    //->where("title LIKE '%" .$searchstring . "%' OR content LIKE '%". $searchstring ."%'")
            $select->where->like('content','%'.$searchstring.'%');
            $select->where->like('title','%'.$searchstring.'%');
        }
    );
    return $resultSet;
```

the lines with the `$select->where->like` are the ones that are ANDed and I want them with OR. What should I change?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no `orWhere` in ZF2, but you could use any combination of `Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate` objects. For OR use 2 predicates in a `PredicateSet` with `PredicateSet::COMBINED_BY_OR`.

There's not much documentation for it, but you could browse the source - for now.

**Edit**: sample

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate;

$select->where(array(
    // ...
    new Predicate\PredicateSet(
        array(
            new Predicate\Like('content', '%'.$searchstring.'%'),
            new Predicate\Like('title', '%'.$searchstring.'%'),
        ),
        Predicate\PredicateSet::COMBINED_BY_OR
    ),
    // ...
));
```

Answer (score 5):

or you cloud use:

```
$select->where
    ->like('content','%'.$searchstring.'%')
    ->or
    ->like('title','%'.$searchstring.'%');
```

Comment: it looks simpler but throws Notice+Error form me:
Undefined property: Zend_Db_Table_Select::$where