# orWhere has disappeared in zf2. How to replace it?

Tags: zend-framework2

Since zf2, orWhere is not possible anymore in query with Zend\Db
I found here ([ZF2 How to orWhere()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056820/zf2-how-to-orwhere)) that it is possible to replace it.
In my example, there is no 'like', only a query like:

```
$select->where("....")->orWhere("...")
```

If using PredicateSet is the only way, how can I use it to make my query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the fluent notation:

```
$where = new Zend\Db\Sql\Where;
$where->OR->equalTo('id', $id);
```

When in doubt, look through the examples Ralph has posted in his Zend_Db-Examples repository (https://github.com/ralphschindler/Zend_Db-Examples).

Answer (score 3):

The **orPredicate** can be used against a **Where()**, like so:

```
public function fetchLike($keyword)
{
    $where = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();
    $pred_url      = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like('url', '%' . $keyword . '%');
    $pred_notes    = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like('notes', '%' . $keyword . '%');
    $pred_username = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like('username', '%' . $keyword . '%');
    $where->orPredicate($pred_url)->orPredicate($pred_notes)->orPredicate($pred_username);

    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select($where);

    return $resultSet;
}
```

Ofcourse you can use **lessThanOrEqualTo**, **equalTo** etc. predicates instead of the like that I used. You can also use the **andPredicate** instead of the **orPredicate**.

[Click here for ZF2's info on predicates](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html#id7)

Also, better to use the namespacing in a proper way;

```
use \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like;
use \Zend\Db\Sql\Where;
// Now you can use code like this:
$pred_url      = new Like('url', '%' . $keyword . '%');
// Instead of
$pred_url      = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like('url', '%' . $keyword . '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now called `orPredicate()` See code within `Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Predicate.php`

Please also see the documentation for [Zend\Db\Sql\Select](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html#where-having) regarding the `where()` function, which you can pass a second parameter that defines the combination of either `AND` or `OR`

Comment: Thanks
I found orPredicate() function in PredicateSet.php but I can't figure out how to use it.
I didn't find any information I could use in Predicate.php (this seems to be for function like like(), equalTo(), etc but can't find out a simple orWhere).

Answer (score 0):

For your example, if you don't use LIKE, you can do it as follows (was looking for a solution quite a bit myself):

```
    $select->where(
        array(
            new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\PredicateSet(array(
                new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Operator('first_column', \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Operator::OPERATOR_EQUAL_TO, $some_value),
                new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Operator('second_column', \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Operator::OPERATOR_EQUAL_TO, $some_value)
                /* even more columns to compare this way... */
            ), 
            \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\PredicateSet::COMBINED_BY_OR)
        )
    );
```