# Clauses OR Where in Zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db

I'm new to ZF2.
How can I write a query like this?

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1 AND status != 2
```

My code Model:

```
public function getUser($where = array())
    {
        $select = $this->sql->select();
        $select->from(self::TABLE);
        $select->where($where);
        $select->order('name ASC');
        return $statement->execute();
    }
```

I am using: Zend\Db\Sql

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the docs [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html).
So `$where` can be a `string` or `Closure`, too.

Call it in your case like:

```
$user = $object->getUser('status != 2');
```

Oh, I missed the first condition:

```
$user = $object->getUser(array('id = 1', 'status != 2'));
```

EDIT:

You can for sure leave the `= array()` default value. I don't know why but I confused it with type hinting. `(array $where)`

Comment: Ok to make a query like this: SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1 AND status = 2 OR status = 3

Comment: try: `$object->getUser(array('id = 1', 'status = 2 OR status = 3'))`. but better look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056820/zf2-how-to-orwhere

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getUser( where = array() ) {
    $select = $this->sql->select();
    $select->from(self::TABLE);

    $select
       ->where->nest()
           ->equalTo( 'id' => where['id'] )
           ->or
           ->notEqualTo( 'status' => where['status'] )
       ->unnest();

    $select->order('name ASC');

    return $statement->execute();
}
```

use like this:

```
getUser( array(
    'id'     => 1,
    'where'  => 2,
) );
```